# How to find the closest points (samples) in the principal component analysis?

Tags: r

I have done the principal component analysis and determined the eigenvectors. I have eigenvectors 1 as eg.1 and eigenvectors 2 as eg.2. Now, I need to find the closest points to each of these data points. What would be the easiest way to do this?

```
    eg.1<- structure(c("-0.013692", "-0.012993", "-0.014427", "-0.01494", 
    "-0.014326", "-0.013538", "-0.017239", "-0.013356", "-0.010027", 
    "-0.015561"), .Names = c("1749742002_A", "1749742086_A", "1749742184_A", 
    "1749742205_A", "1749742207_A", "1749742218_A", "1749742249_A", 
    "1749742273_A", "1749742304_A", "1749742312_A"))

eg.2<-structure(c("-0.00877", "-0.011291", "-0.007758", "-0.010291", 
"-0.006252", "-0.009363", "-0.00983", "-0.00808", "-0.009204", 
"-0.007369"), .Names = c("1749742002_A", "1749742086_A", "1749742184_A", 
"1749742205_A", "1749742207_A", "1749742218_A", "1749742249_A", 
"1749742273_A", "1749742304_A", "1749742312_A"))
```

Comment: What do you mean by `the closest points to each of these data points`?

Comment: @PaulHiemstra I mean distance between the points.

Comment: You mean the closes points in normal space, or probably in PCA space?

Comment: @PaulHiemstra Yes that's correct, I meant the closest points in PCA space.

Comment: Hmm, for that you do not need to perform cross-validation. [Creating a distance matrix](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/dist.html), and getting the smallest distance from that should be sufficient.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra I will try that. Thank you so much.